# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError al ejecutar un JAR

Tags: java, firebase, netbeans, jar

estoy tratando de realizar un clean and build para obtener el jar, pero al ejecutar el jar me da este fallo, que en el entorno no me daba. Es una aplicación Maven que accede a una base de datos Firebase y me da el fallo de java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError a esta librería: com/google/cloud/firestore/EventListener

Esto es un pantallazo desde el cmd ejecutando el jar (obvien los mensajes de directorio creado)
[image]

Mi archivo POM.xml es el siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí esta la implementación de la conexión a la base de datos. En el entorno netbeans me ejecuta perfectamente, pero al ejecutar el jar no.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Supongo que al realizar el build no me coge esa clase, pero no se como agregarla, he buscado un buen rato y no se que más hacer. Gracias.**

Comment: Nos gustaria poderte ayudar, pero para ello debes respetar las normas del sitio. No uses imágenes para pegar código. Léete [ask] y de paso haz el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona este sitio y que preguntas son aceptadas por la comunidad. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta con los cambios para recibir mejor ayuda, gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que indica dicha excepción (`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`) es que no ha encontrado en el *classpath* una clase de la cual depende el programa, por lo que no ha podido ser cargada durante la ejecución de este.

Esto no te ocurre cuando ejecutas el programa desde NetBeans porque este se encarga de agregar el JAR que contiene dicha clase (las dependencias declaradas en el POM) al *classpath*.

Para solucionarlo debes indicarle al comando `java` que agregue las dependencias de tu aplicación al *classpath*.

El comando sería algo como esto (solo tendrías que asegurarte de usar la ruta correcta al JAR de firebase que necesitas):

```
> java -cp C:\User\jpere\.m2\repository\com\google\firebase\firebase-admin-8.1.0.jar -jar MarcadorPadel-1.0.jar
```